# Link only flag declined

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, community-user

I recently flagged an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35611701/1) which only had a link on it's body. I used custom flag and stated that the answer contains only a link. But my flag was declined, and the reason is

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I've two questions about this:

1. Why is my flag declined ? Is link only answer acceptable to SO ?
2. When I checked the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35611701/revisions) I saw that the "Community" user is the major contributor, who added the contents of that link to that particular answer. If community user is going to do this to all "Link only answers" then why we having the **Link Only Answer** flag in the low quality post review queue?

**Update**

I'm answering the second question myself.

As said by [Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317878/community-user-added-more-content-to-a-link-only-answer-and-declined-my-flag#comment314688_317878)

> FYI: An anonymous user suggested the edit. Once approved, it gets
>   assigned to the community user. So it's not really the community user
>   doing anything.

It is edited by an anonymous user (I was unaware of these kind of edits, sorry for that. I blamed Community user ;) )

Comment: FYI: An anonymous user suggested the edit. Once approved, it gets assigned to the community user. So it's not really the community user doing anything.

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for the info, I was unaware of that. Should this kind of edits from an anonymous user acceptable ?

Comment: That's why they go through a review. If 3 users with the appropriate amount of reputation think it's fine, I don't see why the origin of the edit would matter.

Answer (score 6):

There is no automated system here making edits. An anonymous users suggested an edit to the post which was approved, and it was attributed to the Community user since there is no user account to associate with it.

Your flag was not declined because of this, though. Your flag was declined because it was invalid. Yes, there is a link in the answer. But even without the context edited into the post, the answer still answers the question on-site. It explicitly states that they need to declare their properties as dynamic - the link was provided for further context.

Comment: So are you telling that providing an one-line answer and providing the reason of that as a link is fine ? Without adding much information in the answer itself ? So under which circumstances an answer can be considered as link only answer ?

Comment: When I read that answer first I was not sure why he said that, for understanding why, I read the content of that link attached. I prefer adding necessary details along with that answer could be a fine thing.

Comment: @MidhunMP, an answer such as "Try this --> [link]" is going to get clobbered. An answer that is very short (an attempt at an answer) plus a link might stand up quite easily.